# need to implement thousand of potentially overlapping events

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

So i have a web app written in node.js and using a mysql database. currently i have to query the database frequently to make sure the notifications get sent when events are about to start.

What i would like to do is integrate google calendar functionality so that i'm notified of when an event is about to start, and therefore significantly reduce the number of mysql queries i have make.

But i **do not** want to make the user sign in with their emails as i would like to keep the existing experience the same, but with less server load.

How feasible would it be to have an account set up that keeps track of potentially thousands of events, many of which will be overlapping. Is this even worth considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer!

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486

if a single user creates more than 10,000 events in a short period their write access will stop temporarily. if i ever feel like i'll go over the limit, ill make another google account and also make a new field in my database that tells which account to use, splitting the api calls.